# WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D - VMWare, Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, javafx-8, vmware

I realize there is a similar question already on SO, however, that question has nothing to do with VMWare, and I would like to find out if this is more of a VMWare problem or a Linux problem in general.

I receive below WARNING in eclipse when creating an animated 3D Sphere:

```
May 17, 2015 5:35:35 PM javafx.scene.shape.Mesh <init> WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
```

The sphere is 3D and animated when compiled in Windows. In Ubuntu it is only 2D and static.

Host Win 8.1 
Nvidia 660m
VM Workstation 11 (3d acceleration enabled, VM ware tools up-to-date)
Ubuntu 15.04 LTS

Any shared user experience would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to print to the console the graphic pipeline used with this option on command-line:

```
-Dprism.verbose=true
```

and check that it is effectively using hardware accelaration.

For the 3D part, note that 3D is an experimental feature in JavaFX for Linux/ARM and it is not completely implemented.

Some parts may work if you enable this feature with the command-line option:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.experimental.embedded.3d=true
```

Also, you may have to enable the depth buffer too:

```
-Dprism.glDepthSize=24
```

Anyway, there is not guarantee this is going to work...

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same error trying to use JFXScad. What fixed it for me was the option:

`-Dprism.forceGPU=true`

found at:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3653015

Comment: great answer, worked on raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if people are still interested in this post but I had the same issue on Ubuntu Linux.
I done the following to fix the issue
I checked my dependencies and noticed some of the JavaFX jar files were doubled up. So I removed all JavaFX dependencies and from where I downloaded the JavaFX libraries to I included the pack of dependencies for JavaFX 17 jar files and then I was able to build and run a Java3D scene with JavaFX

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).